# Android trusted credentials and OkHttp

Tags: android, ssl, x509certificate, okhttp

I'm a little confused on how to use the system trusted credentials with OkHttp.  I'm using the following code:

```
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            String algo = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf =TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algo);
            tmf.init(ks);
            TrustManager managers[]= tmf.getTrustManagers();
            X509TrustManager defaultTrustMgr = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < managers.length; i++) {
                if (managers[i] instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                    defaultTrustMgr = (X509TrustManager) managers[i];
                }
            }
            X509Certificate[] x509Certificates = defaultTrustMgr.getAcceptedIssuers();
            sslContext.init(null, managers, null);
```

However when I'm using charles I'm still able to sniff the traffic thus allowing for a man in the middle attack.  How do I configure OkHttp to use the default certs that come with Android?

Thanks, Graeme

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly configure OkHttp's socket factory:

```
okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Previously OkHttp used the system default socket factory, but this was problematic. In particular, configuring that socket factory to support NPN and ALPN for SPDY and HTTP/2 caused other code that shared that socket factory to crash.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Does this use the default certificates though?  It seems like I can still Charles the traffic and manipulate it.